# How to convert in columns from row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

My current result

```
Action Name                Is Deleted
--------------------------------------
Account Detail Tap             0
Travel Insurance Tap           0
Blacklist Tap                  0
```

I want this result

```
Account Detail Tap    Travel Insurance Tap     Blacklist Tap
-----------------------------------------------------------
        0                     0                       0
```

My current query

```
SELECT 
    [AM].ActionNameEnglish, [RSM].IsDeleted
FROM 
    ScreenMaster [SM] 
INNER JOIN
    ActionMaster [AM] ON [SM].ScreenID = [AM].ScreenID 
INNER JOIN
    RoleScreenMapping [RSM] ON [AM].ActionID = [RSM].ActionID
WHERE 
    [SM].ScreenID = 1031 
    AND [RSM].IsDeleted = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem a little desperate...  First BREATHE, like your surgeon, you don't want a coder who is frazzled.

This will pivot your subquery into ONE record.   If you add ScreenID to the subquery and remove WHERE portion, you can get more records

```
Select *
 From (
        SELECT [AM].ActionNameEnglish
             , [RSM].IsDeleted
        FROM   ScreenMaster [SM] 
         INNER JOIN ActionMaster [AM] ON [SM].ScreenID = [AM].ScreenID 
         INNER JOIN RoleScreenMapping [RSM] ON [AM].ActionID = [RSM].ActionID
         WHERE [SM].ScreenID = 1031 AND [RSM].IsDeleted = 0
      ) Src
 Pivot (max(IsDeleted) for ActionNameEnglish in ([Account Detail Tap],[Travel Insurance Tap],[Blacklist Tap]) ) Pvt
```

Answer (score 1):

--You can write query like below to get column dynamically

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl (ActionName varchar(255), IsDeleted INT)

insert into #tbl values ('Account Detail Tap',0)
insert into #tbl values ('Travel Insurance Tap',0)
insert into #tbl values ('Blacklist Tap',0)


select * from #tbl

DECLARE @COL VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(2000)
select @col = COALESCE(@col + ', ','') + QUOTENAME(ActionName)
from #tbl Group by ActionName
Set @Query='select * from (select [ActionName],IsDeleted from #tbl) src 
PIVOT (Max(IsDeleted) FOR ActionName
IN ('+@col+')) pvt'
EXEC(@Query)

DROP TABLE #tbl
```